# Why does my MacBookPro keep on hitting Apple servers non-stop?

Tags: windows-7, macbook-pro, boot-camp

Installed Windows 7 on my MBP via Boot Camp and I kept on seeing packets of data hitting a bunch of IP addresses that are apparently within the block that Apple owns.  I blocked them.  Now it tries to hit it non-stop literally every 2 seconds.

Does anyone have an idea why it does that? What is it trying to transmit?

Comment: What's telling you about the packets?

Comment: If you disable Bonjour and other related services, does the traffic stop? I suspect blocking them has increased the frequency simply because it is trying desperately to phone home.

Comment: @techie007 WireShark